# Added a Javascript object to another Javascript object

Tags: javascript, object, associative-array

Alright, so this is doing my head in and I don't know what to do. I have the following two objects

```
records = {A: {subdomain: "testing", ip_address: "222.222.222.22"}}
thisRecord = {subdomain: "test", ip_address: "111.111.111.111"}
```

I'm Trying to add `thisRecord` to the end of `records.A`.

It seems rather simple, but I can't for the life of me figure this out.

Help... Please!

Comment: So `records.A` will have both the first object defined in records _and_ `thisRecord`?

Comment: There seems to be something missing from your question. Either way, it seems like you want to `records.A` to be an **array**. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) to learn about arrays.

Comment: @NickZuber thisRecord is the local record of a loop, and gets overwritten each time the loop runs.

Comment: @FelixKling I didn't think that arrays would work as you have to have an integer key for those, not an associative one.

Comment: Wait, so you want `records.A` to be overwritten with `thisRecord`? That contradicts what you state in your question.

Comment: Then you have to explain what exactly you mean by *"add `thisRecord` to the end of `records.A`"*. `records.A` is an *object* (`{subdomain: "testing", ip_address: "222.222.222.22"}`), it doesn't have an "end".

Comment: how would you like the records to look like after appending and what will you do with it

Comment: @FelixKling `thisRecord` getting appended to `records.A`, or `records.CNAME` or `records.TXT`, whatever ever the current record might be. `thisRecord` is simply a temp object to store the current record when fetching data

Comment: @LeeR So, just to be clear, after the "appending" process, `records.A` will have two objects as its value?

Comment: @NickZuber Correct. I think I misread Felix earlier about the use of Array's. I think I get how to make it work now.

Comment: Sorry @FelixKling I misread you earlier. I get what you mean about `records.A` being an *array* now

Comment: Well, I can see how it could be interpreted the other way ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7vepkb3c/)**

You should structure your `records.A` object as an array of objects:

```
records = {
  A: [
       {
         subdomain: "testing",
         ip_address: "222.222.222.22"
       }
  ]
}
```

Then, whenever you want to append new data, simply push it onto `records.A`

```
thisRecord = {subdomain: "test", ip_address: "111.111.111.111"}

// Append your new record to `records.A`
records.A.push(thisRecord);
```

Your `records.A` will then look like:

```
records = {
  A: [
       {
         subdomain: "testing",
         ip_address: "222.222.222.22"
       },
       {
         subdomain: "test",
         ip_address: "111.111.111.111"
       }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly then records["A"] needs to be an array to hold both the objects. Assuming this is the case you can do something like this

```
newRecord = {}
newRecord.A = []
newRecord.A.push(records.A);
newRecord.A.push(thisRecord);
records = newRecord;
```

Comment: No need for bracket notation. Use dot notation: `records.A`. You can also directly write `newRecord = {A: [records.A, thisRecord]}`.